# SonarQube API Metric name to fetch LOC since previous analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I know that the metric name to be used for fetching **LOC** through SonarQube API is "**ncloc**".

I want to fetch "LOC since previous analysis", which usually shows on the UI as +xxx or -xxx (xxx being the lines of code).
I went through the entire documentation, but couldn't find the metric name for this.
Is there any such metric provided in the SonarQube API?

The SonarQube version I'm working on is 5.1.

Comment: The version you're on is >1.5 years old & came before the most recent LTS. You're not likely to get a lot of help on this, but AIR, this metric is not available in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. For anyone else, if it might help, there is no direct parameter name for "LOC since previous analysis". But it is possible to get the same, by using the property

> includetrends

in the URL when making the call to Sonarqube API. You need to use this property with the value set to **true**.

So the URL would be http://sonarqube/api/resources?metrics=ncloc&includetrends=true